# Sort JS object by japanese alphabet

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have list of regions in an object, and want to sort them according to the Japanese alphabet:

```
Object JP-01 : "Hokkido [北海道]" JP-02 : "Aomori-ken [青森県]" JP-03 : "Iwate-ken [岩手県]" JP-04 : "Miyagi-ken [宮城県]
```

How do I do that, maybe with angular?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Are you sorting an array of strings? Or a non-array object? (If the latter, it's generally a bad idea to try to sort objects; you can only affect property order when building the object originally and the rules are both new and [slightly] complicated.) What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Note that the [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method of strings may be useful to you.

Comment: These might help you:

1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764269/what-does-sorting-mean-in-non-alphabetic-i-e-asian-languages

2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: Object
JP-01
:
"Hokkido [北海道]"
JP-02
:
"Aomori-ken [青森県]"
JP-03
:
"Iwate-ken [岩手県]"
JP-04
:
"Miyagi-ken [宮城県]"

Comment: sorting this object

Comment: this date comes form json

Comment: it's very big json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function [String.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) that supports different languages. Here's an example:

```js
var obj = {
 "JP-01": "Hokkido [北海道]",
 "JP-02": "Aomori-ken [青森県]",
 "JP-03": "Iwate-ken [岩手県]",
 "JP-04": "Miyagi-ken [宮城県]"
};

console.log(Object.values(obj).sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b, 'ja');
}));
```

With that, you'll recieve an array with the regions sorted.

Comment: First, tou have to extract `a` and `b` from those strings.

Comment: That's true, I forget that. I'll change my answer, thanks!

Comment: how to use this this is object in a object

Comment: "obj" is your object, and "Object" is the object prototype. I'll edit the answer to show you that.

Comment: Looks like it sorts incorrectly. check `['日本語 [ja]', '英語 [en]']`. You need to use it like this: a.localeCompare(b, 'ja')